# How does Cold Blooded work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Wizard's Cold Blooded passive says "Cold damage dealt to chilled and frozen targets is increased by 20%".  While 'frozen' is pretty obvious (although there aren't many ways to freeze targets) 'chilled' is a bit less obvious.  What specifically qualifies as a debuff to allow for this bonus damage?

For example, the reduced movement speed from the Ice Armor Chilling Armor rune specifically says the targets become chilled, but Ray of Frost's effect seems to do the same thing but doesn't say that...are they treated the same?  How can I tell what qualifies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has yet to be officially confirmed, but people's experience has indicated that anytime a blue effect is applied to a target and it is snared, that is considered "Chilled", and Cold Blooded will apply additional damage. This means that skills that do not officially mention "Chilled" will still apply it, such as Blizzard and Ray of Frost.

This can be confirmed by looking at the Ray of Frost damage with Cold Blooded as a passive - the first hit should do substantially less damage than subsequent hits.

Comment: Does any time a blue effect is applied the target is snared and chilled?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the info i gathered on this in this post.

[How much time does the chilled debuff last on mobs after being applied in diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/72965/27402)

Only thing unanswered is that the chilled status also seems to apply some attack speed reduction but no idea how much it is.

Note that ray of frost mov speed reduction is coming from the skill itself and NOT from the chilled status since it does not apply that.

If you get a spell that does apply the chilled status,like blizzard,mouvement speed reduction does stack.Chilled + ray of frost 60% mov speed reduction.

Starting to be a lot info posted here but i actually tested it and mov.speed reduction cant get to 100%.There is actually a solid cap on that.
Im gonna go ahead and suppose the cap is 80% since the time bubble spell has a rune to increase the mov.speed reduction to 80% in one spell.

Comment: I can see how this is tangentially related, but I don't see how it answers my question...

Comment: Only thing left for you is to find out which spells apply the chilled debuff, frozen armor with the chilled aura for exemple applies chilled debuff to anything that gets within range near you.Blizzard applies it as well.Once chilled, then cold blooded rune 20% for any cold damage effect apply, using ray of frost for exemple which is cold damage.using trancendant blades with a cold damage attribute weapon on as well would get the boost.

Comment: That's all well and good - my question is asking for exactly that list of what applies the debuff.  If you know, you should answer; otherwise this is just a non sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are chilled or frozen, the damage is increased for any source meaning that if you chill them with blizzard then use disintegrate, the damage is increased for both spells. The chill has to be applied from a cold spell, but the damage increase is for any spell type.