# How much time does the chilled debuff last on mobs after being applied in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

How much time does the chilled debuff last on mobs after being applied in Diablo 3?

I would like to know so I can plan accordingly my build on my wizard to cast a chilled/cold/frozen damage spell so the cold blooded rune 20% damage increase can apply.

Must be just a few seconds but how much exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need?

http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/ice-armor

Comment: Thanks, it does help.Info on that page would imply that the chilled debuff last for 2 seconds and applies a 30% slow.Nice information.

Comment: Now i just also realised that a cold damage weapon is not applying the chilled debuff by itself and also that the ray of frost spell does not apply a chilled debuff either ,it just does cold damage.Going to have to plan accordingly since its after an enemy is chilled or frozen that the 20% damage increase from the rune can apply to the cold damage that you inflict then.

Comment: @paradebor if you find the information helpful please accept the answer. Click the tick to the left of it(and upvote if you can) ;)

Comment: That's what I've been asking all over the place. Does cold damage actually apply chilled effect. It seems that the answer is yes.